# Difference between read only and visible

Tags: custom-field

can some one please explain what is the difference between visible and read only in field level security while creating fields. I am very confused.

Answer (score 6):

**Visible :**
If you check the "Visible" checkbox, that field will be visible to that profile. User can read & edit that field

**Read-Only:**
If you check the "Read-Only" checkbox, that field will be read only for the users of that profile. User can only see that field, he can't edit. Field must be *Visible* to be *Read-Only*

Comment: Also, the field must be *Visible* to be *Read-Only*.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edit my answer.

Comment: Don't hesitate to set answer as `Accepted` if it helps you to help other users .